# How to Enable Publication Option in Sql server 2012 for Replication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-replication

I want to replication in sql server 2012 but when i right click Replication i cannot see the New "Publication Option". I see "New Replication Monitor" option. Please see image. Anyone please guide how to enable or bring back publication option when right click on it, thanks.

[image]

Comment: Unless you have a penchant for odd naming conventions for your instances, or Microsoft changed things between the 2008 and 2012 versions, you're not going to succeed. SQL Server *Express* supports being a subscriber but not a publisher.

Comment: And this does appear to still be the case for [2012](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.110).aspx#Replication)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Do you mean SQL server express 2012 has not this functionality? I didn't understand much as you explain. Please suggest a simple and straight forward way, thanks.

Comment: That's correct. SQL Server Express cannot be a Publisher.

Comment: Thanks, how to mark as an answer to your comments?.